# How to use dplyr:mutate to mulitply pairs of columns specified by parts of the variable name

Tags: r, names, dplyr

I have the following example:

```
df <- data.frame(
id = c(1,2,3),
  fix_01.2012 = c(2,5,7),
  fix_02.2012 = c(5,1,7),
  fix_03.2012 = c(6,1,5),
  fox_01.2012 = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.7),
  fox_02.2012 = c(0.6, 0.5, 0.8),
  fox_03.2012 = c(0.7, 0.5, 0.9)
  )

  id fix_01.2012 fix_02.2012 fix_03.2012 fox_01.2012 fox_02.2012 fox_03.2012
1  1           2           5           6         0.4         0.6         0.7
2  2           5           1           1         0.5         0.5         0.5
3  3           7           7           5         0.7         0.8         0.9
```

The table below is what I want to  get. 
I want to create a new column for each date (e.g. "01.2012"):

res_date = fix_date * fox_date

As I have many dates / pairs of dates, I guess this needs to be done by looping through the names.

```
 id fix_01.2012 fix_02.2012 fix_03.2012 fox_01.2012 fox_02.2012 fox_03.2012 res_01.2012 res_02.2012 res_03.2012
1  1           2           5           6         0.4         0.6         0.7         0.8         3.0         4.2
2  2           5           1           1         0.5         0.5         0.5         2.5         0.5         0.5
3  3           7           7           5         0.7         0.8         0.9         4.9         5.6         4.5
```

Anyone can help? Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much more verbose than the other answers, but to my eye easier to read/edit/adapt, is a heavy gather-spread approach (the way I'd reason the problem if I was solving it step-by-step):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  gather(-id, key=colname, value=value) %>% 
  separate(colname, c('fixfox', 'date'), sep='_') %>% 
  spread(key=fixfox, value=value) %>% 
  mutate(res=fix*fox) %>% 
  gather(-id, -date, key=colname, value=value) %>% 
  unite(new_colname, colname, date, sep='_') %>% 
  spread(key=new_colname, value=value)
```

Comment: Yes, agree. This is a very nice approach making it easy to read and adapt. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea that uses `split.default` to split the data frame based on similar column names (based on your conditions). We then loop over that list and multiply the columns. In this case, we use `Reduce` (rather than `i[1]*i[2]`) to multiply in order to account for more than two columns

```
do.call(cbind, 
   lapply(split.default(df[-1], gsub('.*_', '', names(df[-1]))), function(i) Reduce(`*`, i)))

#     01.2012 02.2012 03.2012
#[1,]     0.8     3.0     4.2
#[2,]     2.5     0.5     0.5
#[3,]     4.9     5.6     4.5
```

Bind them back to the original with `cbind.data.frame()`

Comment: Using `sapply` reduces `do.call` step. `sapply(split.default(df[-1], gsub('.*_', '', names(df[-1]))), function(i) Reduce(`*`, i))` Nice answer BTW.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a `tidyverse` approach, it will take using a bit of tidy evaluation to get what you want.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2,3),
  fix_01.2012 = c(2,5,7),
  fix_02.2012 = c(5,1,7),
  fix_03.2012 = c(6,1,5),
  fox_01.2012 = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.7),
  fox_02.2012 = c(0.6, 0.5, 0.8),
  fox_03.2012 = c(0.7, 0.5, 0.9)
)

# colnames with "fix" 
fix <- names(df)[grepl("fix",names(df))]

# colnames with "fox"
fox <- names(df)[grepl("fox",names(df))]

# Iterate over the two vectors of names and column bind the results (map2_dfc).  
# Since these are strings, we need to have them evaluated as symbols
# Creating the column name just requires the string to be evaluated.

map2_dfc(fix, fox, ~transmute(df, !!paste0("res", str_extract(.x, "_(0\\d)")) := !!sym(.x) * !!sym(.y)))

#>   res_01 res_02 res_03
#> 1    0.8    3.0    4.2
#> 2    2.5    0.5    0.5
#> 3    4.9    5.6    4.5
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the explanations! This makes it easy to follow your approach.

Comment: Very concise code! This requires the columns to be in the right order though, right? Otherwise the wrong pairs will be multiplied with each other.